# Call Method with specific element as event-referrer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bug causing me not being able to trigger a "dblclick()"-Event on an element where it is binded like this:

```
<span id="1" ondblclick="myMethod();">Click!</span>
```

I actually can't tell why it is not working but it seems to be caused by some huge old javascript running in the background.

**I tried:**

```
$('#1').trigger('dblclick');
$('#1').trigger('ondblclick');
$('#1').dblclick();
```

I would need to fire the myMethod() but this one's depending on a given "evt"-Variable storing some information about the element being fired. Is there a way to get this element as "evt-referrer" to call the myMethod() **without having to trigger a dblclick()**?

This would prevent me from *huge* changes on the code (myMethod()) or troubleshooting for the dblclick-event.

**Solution:**
Never mind, found out that a click-event fired two times in a row will occur in a doubleclick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery triggers only events that are attached by jQuery. To trigger native events do:

```
// 1) remove 'ondblclick'-attribute from span in html
// 2) get the element
var elem = document.getElementById('1');
// 3) attach  eventListener to element in native way
elem.addEventListener('dblclick', myMethod);
// 4) trigger the event in native way
elem.dispatchEvent(
    new Event('dblclick', {bubbles: true});
);
```

If your `myMethod` depends on an event you can't call it without.

Comment: This one returns true without fireing myMethod() - do I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

events will not trigger the ondoubleclick attr.

ondoubleclick can be fired by

$(elm).click().click(); 
but this is realy dirty!

Comment: I tried this but getting an error: The constructor Example(String) is undefined

Comment: @M41DZ3N A dblclick dispatched native way **does** trigger ondblclick attr.